# Zen Cart - Itemized Shipping Totals

Tags: e-commerce, customization, zen-cart

I'm currently finishing up a fairly customized Zen Cart setup for a client and while overall the site is 99% functional when it comes to ordering, I'm having an issue on the checkout page where the customer is able to see the item totals and the sales tax, along with the grand total.

The issue however is that the grand total accounts for the shipping rate (as shown below the order form) however I'd like to also have it displayed above the sales tax line.

Does anyone know which files I'd need to access to edit the cosmetics of the checkout total?

Aside from that, I'm pretty sure I'd be able to plug in the custom values since I have the variable names on hand from coding the site till now.

Thanks very much in advance for any assistance,

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the totals are displayed is determined by their sort order on the Admin >> Modules >> Order Totals page.

I've changed them this way a few times for clients, but you do need to be check that the tax calculations still work (there have been quite a few changes to recent versions to try to get that right in all cases).